# How to refresh a div on link or button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a small social network project where I am using post comment functionality. What I am stuck with is as soon as the use deletes a comment, the comment count should decrease automatically. This can onyl be done using refresh functionality, but the current code does not seem to be working. It deletes the comment but does not display the decreased count. So whenever a comment is deleted, it should show up the decreased count. Here is my code so far.

```
<div style="border:2px solid red;" class="comment_ui" id="view<?php echo $id; ?>">
<div>
<a href="#" class="view_comments" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">View all <?php echo $comment_count; ?> comments</a>
</div>


<div class="comment_ui">

<div class="comment_text">
  <div  class="comment_actual_text">
    <?php echo $FirstName.' '.$LastName;?>
    <a id="<?php echo $c_id;?>" class = "delete_comment" style="position: relative; float:right; right: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="#">x</a><p/>
    <div id="sssss"><?php echo $comment; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
          $(".delete_comment").click(function(){
            var element = $(this);
            var comment = element.attr("id");
            var commentRow = $(this).closest('.comment_text');
            var info = "comment="+comment;            

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "delete_comment.php",
              data: info,
              success: function(){
                commentRow.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                $('.comment_ui').load(url + ' .comment_ui');                
              }
            });
            return  false;
          });
        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use .load() like that. The variable url isn't defined and you can't add a jquery selector to the url.

If you cant .load() the exact html you need you must .get() it instead, .find() the part you need in the response and insert it with .html()

**EDIT: Added code suggestion**

```
<div style="border:2px solid red;" class="comment_ui" id="view<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="view_comments" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">View all 
            <span id="totalCommentsCount"><?php echo $comment_count; ?></span> comments</a>
    </div>

    <div class="comment_ui">
        <div class="comment_text">
          <div  class="comment_actual_text">
            <?php echo $FirstName.' '.$LastName;?>
            <a id="<?php echo $c_id;?>" class = "delete_comment" style="position: relative; float:right; right: 20px; text-decoration: none;" href="#">x</a><p/>
            <div id="sssss"><?php echo $comment; ?></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".delete_comment").click(onDeleteComment);
    });


    function onDeleteComment() {
        var commentElement = this;
        var commentId = commentElement.id;

        //Start the fade-out even before the delete is committed to create a fast user experience
        var commentRow = $(commentElement).closest('.comment_text');
        commentRow.fadeOut('slow', function() { commentRow.remove(); });

        //Post the delete to the server
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "delete_comment.php",
          data: { comment: commentId },
          success: function (deleteResponse) {

            //USE ONE OF THE ALT. BELOW:

            //Alt.1: delete_comment.php returns a json like { count: 12 } which describes number of comments left
            $('#totalCount').text(deleteResponse.count);

            //Alt.2: you don't care to reload number of comments from server and just decrease by one.
            var totalCountSpan = $('#totalCount');
            totalCountSpan.text(parseInt(totalCountSpan.text()) - 1);

            //Alt.3: get number of comments left on server by reloading the "view" an extra time. Really not optimal!           
            var viewId = $('.comment_ui').attr('id');
            $.get( "get_view.php?id=" + viewId, function( data ) {
                var newCount = $(data).find('#totalCount').text();
                $( "#totalCount" ).text( newCount );
             });             
          },
          error: function(){
                //Possibly restore the comment here if this happens often?
                alert("somthing is wrong")
          },
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: var element = $(this).find('.comment_ui');
And then how do I bring up the html?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".delete_comment").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var comment = element.attr("id");
        var commentRow = $(this).closest('.comment_text');
        var info = "comment="+comment;            

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "delete_comment.php",
          data: info,
          success: function(){
            commentRow.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
             $.post( url + ' .comment_ui', function( data ) {
                $( ".comment_ui" ).html( data );
             })

          },
          error: function(){
                alert("somthing is wrong")
          },
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: after this line $.post( url + ' .comment_ui', function( data ) { alert(data); and check any data come or not

Comment: Then check browser console what error is coming and and which page sending request using post method?